# In BlackBerry 10, how to read a ListView clearSelection() signal parameters?

Tags: blackberry-10

For ListView one can programattically do a [clearSelection()](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__listview.html#function-clearselection):

"This function does not cause signals to be emitted for individual items. Instead, a single [selectionChanged()](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__listview.html#function-selectionchanged-indexpath-selected) is emitted with [ListView::AllItems](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__listview.html#variable-allitems) and false as parameters."

[http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*cascades*_listview.html#function-clearselection](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__listview.html#function-clearselection)

How can I listen for this when clearSelection() is called at onSelectionChanged?

Something like:

```
onSelectionChanged:{
if((!selected)&&(indexPath == listViewid.AllItems)){
//do something
                                                   }
                   }
```

I don't understand " Instead, a singleselectionChanged() is emitted with ListView::AllItems and false as parameters" and how to listen for those paramters.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more as to what you are trying to achieve?  Do you want to call clearSelection() in your onSelectionChanged event or are you wanting to detect when it is called?

Comment: detect when it is called

Comment: I havn't tested, but from what I understand it looks like you could compare the indexPath.size() to the number of items in the list.  If it's the same size (and selected == false) then clearSelection has been called.  The documentation is not overly clear though.  You might also have luck doing a debug of the indexPath to see what it's set to when clearSelection() is called.

Comment: If I listen for indexPath.size()==0 && selected==false that might be a signal for a say a Rename too if my list is of files though, right? I want to listen specifically for clearSelection() only.